# Kafka connect confluent jdbc does not control session pool in MSSQL database

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I am working with Kafka connect and confluent jdbc. Integrate a source connector with Mssql and a few days ago the operating area warned us that there is a high number of sessions in the "sleeping" state in the database. I need to control those sessions but apparently the connector (confluent jdbc) doesn't have those properties in its configuration.

Do you have any ideas to correct this problem?

Comment: How many connectors are you running? How many `tasks.max`?

Comment: we have 27 connectors source (1 per table same database)  each with tasks.max=1 in a cluster with 3 nodes

Comment: Does each connector have different properties or could you combine them?

Comment: Each connectors have the same properties but different query, prefix_topic and different transforms

Comment: Can you explain how connect works with respect to the sessions in the database? That is, if I have 1 connector replicated in a cluster (with 3 nodes) with its task.max = 1, would I have 1 or 3 active sessions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kafka Connect will run a minimum of one task per connector. Each connector is isolated from the other and other than sharing a runtime environment is isolated from the others.

Therefore if you have 27 connectors sourcing from the same database, you will have a minimum of 27 connections to the database.

If you can't reduce the number of connectors (e.g. by have one connector pull from multiple tables), then the only option I think you have is to speak to your DBA about enforcing some kind of resource management on the RDBMS side. For example, on Oracle the Resource Manager option can be used for this.

Comment: Well, I managed to verify that each connector always opens two sessions in the database. Always we have 54 sessions with my 27 connectors (kafka connect 3 nodes). The behavior independent of the number of Kafka Connect nodes, both for an environment with 3 nodes and 1, the result was the same (2 sessions in sleeping state in MSSQL database for each connector). Unfortunately I can't group connectors by some criteria. I will have no choice but to develop a custom connector that can better control the opening of database connections. 
Thanks for your help

Comment: The table monitor thread also opens 1 connection, therefore total connections (per connector) = Min(total tasks, total tables) + 1.